# Unsubscribing in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

How can I unsubscribe in this function after dialog's closeAll method? Is it possible to turn subscription to a variable and then somehow apply it to 'onProjectAdded' instance?

```
    this.dialog
      .open(GridAddDialogComponent)
      .componentInstance.onProjectAdded.subscribe((projectData) => {
        this._gridApi.setRowData([...this.rowData1, projectData]);
      })
      this.dialog.closeAll()
  }
```

Comment: The guidebooks usually recommend to place an unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy. You can find information [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0) and [here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-best-practice-unsubscribing-rxjs-observables/). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Do you want to unsubscribe when the dialog box is closed by the user or at another time ?  Unsubscribing after `this.dialog.closeAll()` might lead to data never coming through since the ubsubscribe function might fire before the observable publishes any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways:
 1. Auto unsubscribe after component destroy:

```
export class ExampleComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  readonly _destroy$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

  constructor(
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dialog
      .open(GridAddDialogComponent)
      .componentInstance.onProjectAdded
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
      .subscribe((projectData) => {
        this._gridApi.setRowData([...this.rowData1, projectData]);
      })
      this.dialog.closeAll();
  }


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroy$.next(null);
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }

}
```

2. Unsubscribe when you need it(in my case afret destroying component but you can do it everywhere):

export class ExampleComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

```
  public subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(
    private readonly dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const subscription = this.dialog
      .open(GridAddDialogComponent)
      .componentInstance.onProjectAdded
      .subscribe((projectData) => {
        this._gridApi.setRowData([...this.rowData1, projectData]);
      });
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((sub) => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

}
```

Also you can use single subscription instead of array of it.